# How to find alternative APIs for deprecated Intel IPP APIs?

Tags: c++, deprecated, intel-ipp, intel-parallel-studio

I am working with [Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (Intel IPP 8.2)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp). I am trying to use one of the [Copy](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/505236) APIs from Utility Functions. The reference manual says "DEPRECATED", but does not provide alternative API.

Can anyone please point out **how to find alternatives for deprecated APIs in general**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [IPP Deprecation Information](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/ipp-deprecated-features-feedback) page. It seems Intel is marking functions as "DEPRECATED" in order to gather feedback and then decide whether to keep the functionality or have it remain as legacy. Though the above page refers to IPP 7.1, as I understand the policy has not changed.

They don't provide an alternative for every function, so there is no general solution. You can however ask in their forum or take a look at [this page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/functions-deprecated-in-ipp-71/) which does provide alternatives for some functions (also for functions deprecated in IPP 7.1).

Comment: Thanks @Navesh! I could find a way to find the alternatives by searching the functionality on their reference pages.
For example, for copy functionality, I searched [this page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/search/site/language/en?query=copy), and selected entries from "Reference Manuals" whose description didn't say deprecated.